# Re-download Windows 8 setup without purchasing it again using Upgrade Assistant

Tags: windows-8

When I tried to re-run the upgrade assistant to re-download Windows 8 setup files, it asked me to purchase Windows 8 again but I have already paid for it.

So, how do I re-download the setup again?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just received an email containing my order information including the Windows 8 product key and a link to download Windows 8 setup.

I clicked on the link `If you need to download Windows, write down your new product key and enter it here` and it started downloading the Windows 8 setup again:

[image]