# My Toshiba Satellite will not boot after windows 8 installation (online)

Tags: boot

I've tired to install windows 8 onto my Toshiba Satellite L745-S4210. Installing windows 8 was fine no errors (It told me to unstall some Toshiba programs) so after it was all done, I restarted my computer to finish the job and to see my laptop on windows 8 and it said "The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error. Windows installation cannot proceed. To install windows, Click "OK" to restart the computer. and the restart the installation" I've looked online and i could not find no answers to my question. I do not have the disc, i bought it online. So if there's someone that could help me please do. I do not want to pay for the program again for the disk

Comment: On su and the rest of the se network, our goal is to not just answer your question but to help others with the same issue. Someone might answer your question here, but no one will be e mailing you. The [faq] will have more info if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

1. See [Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) and [Re-download Windows 8 setup without purchasing it again using Upgrade Assistant](https://superuser.com/questions/501656/re-download-windows-8-setup-without-purchasing-it-again-using-upgrade-assistant) for instructions on how you can re-download the setup files on another PC.
2. This time, when you launch the installer using the link from your confirmation mail, be sure to select the following options so you can either create an ISO to burn to a DVD, or transfer the Win8 installer to a USB stick (more details [here](http://www.guidingtech.com/16395/make-bootable-iso-file-windows-8-pro-after-upgrading/)):

   [image: 1]

   [image: 2]
3. Change the boot order in your BIOS and boot from the DVD or USB stick and run Windows setup.  If you have no important data you can proceed to format your drive and clean install Windows, otherwise use a Linux LiveCD/USB to back up your data to an external hard disk.

Get someone to help you with this if it sounds too complicated, or you might end up losing your important data, if any.